Load VueJS template dynamically

Template is downloaded fully from external location (including root element)
Template can contain bindings
Component is registered as custom element

I tried this one:
async function getTemplate() {
  const response = `
    <div>
      <h1>{{ message }}</h1>
    </div>
  `;

  return await Promise.resolve(response);
}

const MyCustomElement = {
  data() {
    return {
      template: null,
      message: 'Hello, I am a Vue component!'
    };
  },
  async created() {
    this.template = await getTemplate();
  },
  render() {
    if (this.template == null)
        return Vue.h('div', 'Loading...');

    return Vue.h(Vue.compile(this.template)); // ERROR!
  }
};

const element = Vue.defineCustomElement(MyCustomElement);

customElements.define('my-component', element);

Vue.createApp({}).mount('#app');


It says message is not defined. Any ideas why it cannot find the defined property?
Should it be implemented in any other way?
It is VueJS 3, the latest one (3.4.25).

i think you should define getTemplate function in method. because you are using option Api. it 's right?

Better use 
https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics.html#dynamic-components

It seems I have found the solution considering Alexander's answer. To address my question in the comments, we can insert this.$data there. Therefore, my updated code will look as follows:


async function getTemplate() {
  const response = `
    <div>
      <h1>{{ message }}</h1>
    </div>
  `;

  return await Promise.resolve(response);
}

const MyCustomElement = {
  data() {
    return {
      template: null,
      message: 'Hello, I am a Vue component!'
    };
  },
  async created() {
    this.template = await getTemplate();
  },
  render() {
    if (this.template == null)
        return Vue.h('div', 'Loading...');

    return Vue.h(Vue.compile(this.template), this.$data);
  }
};

const element = Vue.defineCustomElement(MyCustomElement);

customElements.define('my-component', element);

Vue.createApp({}).mount('#app');
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Vue Component Example</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/3.4.25/vue.global.prod.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="app">
  <my-component></my-component>
</div>





You should create your app with the element: Vue.createApp(() => Vue.h('my-component'))
Vue.h should be fed with props passed to the template Vue.h(Vue.compile(this.template), {message: this.message}):



async function getTemplate() {
  const response = `
    <div>
      <h1>{{ message }}</h1>
    </div>
  `;

  return new Promise(r => setTimeout(() => r(response), 500));
}

const MyCustomElement = {
  data() {
    return {
      template: null,
      message: 'Hello, I am a Vue component!'
    };
  },
  async created() {
    this.template = await getTemplate();
  },
  render() {
    if (this.template == null)
        return Vue.h('div', 'Loading...');

    return Vue.h(Vue.compile(this.template), {message: this.message}); // ERROR!
  }
};

const element = Vue.defineCustomElement(MyCustomElement);

customElements.define('my-component', element);

Vue.createApp(() => Vue.h('my-component')).mount('#app');
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/3.4.8/vue.global.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>




Nice, we moved one step further, even there is no need to create node at createApp. My HTML contains custom element . All is solved by this update: Vue.h(Vue.compile(this.template), {message: this.message}); But how I can use original data() object? Especially if I need 2-way data binding in loaded template.
